# How to open a Google search based on user input

Tags: javascript

I am building  chatbot using JavaScript and now I want it to Google stuff.

What I want to do is to type anything and then the function will `window.open` to the Google page. For example if I type `google cars` it will open a page with cars link: `https://www.google.com/search?q=cars`.

Can this be done with JavaScript?

This is what I did so far:

```
function takeInput(e) {

    // enter === 13

    if(e.which != 13) {
        return false;
    }

    var question = this.value;

    appendOutput("<p><b>HUMAN : </b>" + question + "</p>", output);
    appendOutput("<p><b>CHATBOT : </b>" + processInput(question) + "</p>", output);
    appendOutput('<hr/>', output);

    this.focus();
    this.select();

    output.scrollByLines(100);
}

function processInput(question) {
    var answer = "I cannot answer this question";

    if (question.toUpperCase() == "GOOGLE ") {
        answer = "Here is what I found on Google:";
        window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=');
    }
}
```

Comment: More code please, pretty hard to tell what you've tried and what you're after

Comment: @CharlieWynn I Put some more code as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok lets break this down:

1. You want to build a *chatbox* which takes input from a user.
2. The chatbox will do a Google search when google is used before the question, such as google [question statement].
3. Then, after some event is triggered such as a button click, enter key or anything else you want, it will open a new window and do a Google search based on the [question statement].

I took the above points and came up with this implementation:

## JavaScript

```
(function(){
    var googleBox = document.getElementById("googleBox"),
        searchButton = document.getElementById("searchButton");

  searchButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var userInput = googleBox.value,
        regex_google = new RegExp('google(.*)');

    if(userInput.match(/^([\w\-]+)/)[1].toLowerCase() === "google"){ // matches the first word in the string, which should be 'google'

      window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + userInput.match(regex_google)[1].trim());
    }
  });
})();
```

## HTML

```
<textarea name="googleBox" id="googleBox" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
<button id="searchButton">Search</button>
```

I am using a `textarea` to represent a chatbox, basically type stuff in it and get the user to send it somewhere via an event. In this case I am using a button, but you can do whatever you like, such as combining the above to also check for the `keydown` event for `enter` to be pressed by the keyboard.

I then grab the user input, I use Regex to get the first word using the regular expression match: `^([\w\-]+)`

If this is true, which it must be if I interpret your question correctly, then I use `window.open` to do a google search on the contents of the user input **after** the word google, using the regular expression: `google(.*)`.

Feel free to play around with it in this **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AGE/vczcrzo6/)**.

Any questions? Please ask in the comments below.

Comment: As a matter of fact i am building a "chatbot" not a "chatbox". So the user says something in an <input> and the bot answers. In this case i wanted to know if there is a javascript wildcard ( i dont know how you call it ) that will be able to do this :

user : google * 
chatbot: Here is what i found on google: 

what the chatbot will do is also make a window.open('https://www.google.com/search?q=" + "*");


*  =   whatever the user puts after google ( for example google cars or google facebook etc)

Comment: I would like to better understand what you mean by a wildcard, also what is this chatbot exactly supposed to do?

Comment: What i want it to do is if the user says "google cars" , the chatbot will be able to open a new window and show the result on google for cars. The chatbot is supposed to make google searches, set reminders,compose emails etc. I already made this chatbot with AIML but now i want it to make it again using JavaScript since you can do more things with javascript. Sorry if i confused you with the word "wildcard".

Comment: You can tie your chatbot code, if it is written in JavaScript, to listen to user input in the exact same way I did on the answer. JavaScript only needs you to use Event Handlers to listen to user actions, in this case you can have the chatbot trigger this behavior from their end using the same code.